# Solving $y=a\log\left(bx\right)$ using the least squares method

Tags: statistics, regression

How do I solve for $a$ and $b$ in $y=a\log\left(bx\right)$ using the method of least squares? I tried using
$$10^y = \left(bx\right)^a$$
but I end up with terms containing both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
y = a\log{bx} = a\log{b} + a\log{x} = \left|
\begin{aligned}
\beta_0 &= a\log{b} \\ 
\beta_1 &= a \\
X &= \log{x}
\end{aligned}
\right| = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X
$$

You can define estimates $\beta_0, \beta_1$ by the least squares method.

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= \beta_1 \\
\beta_0 &= a\log{b} \Leftrightarrow \beta_0 = \beta_1\log{b} \Leftrightarrow \log{b} = \frac{\beta_0}{\beta_1}  \Leftrightarrow b = e^\frac{\beta_0}{\beta_1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$y=a\log\left(bx\right)\implies y=a(log(b)+\log(x))=a\log(b)+a\log(x)$$ Define $c=a\log(b)$ and $z=\log(x)$.

That's it